# Images sometimes come sometimes not in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, repeat

I am new to angular and just stuck in a problem, I cant figure out why the image is not showing, sometime it comes but sometimes its not. I check the console too, there is no error.

```
<div class="main">
         <ul>
             <li class="two" ng-repeat="items in student | filter : query | orderBy: studentOrder : direction"> 
             <!--we use ng-src because when we run the file the angular.min.js file reads the html fot image so we get an error in console -->
             <a class="link" href="#/details/{{student.indexOf(items)}}">
             <img class="image" ng-src="images/{{items.image}}.JPG"  alt="Photo is not availble"> 

             <p class="four">{{items.name | uppercase}}
                 </br>
             </p>
             <p class="five"> 
                 {{items.univeristy | lowercase}} 
             </p> 
             </a>
             <hr>

             </li>

         </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: I am following lynda tutorial btw.

Comment: In your controller.. where u have written `student = somedata ` try a line after this `$scope.$apply(); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your referencing uppercase `JPG` everytime. It sounds like some images have `JPG` meaning they will work. But more often than not images are a mixture of various people's naming convention. Please check that all image paths are correct.

--

On a side note, there are a few ways you could improve your code. Firstly I've taken the liberty at assuming your students object.

*Please provide this in future as it will lead to more accurate answers*

I have changed your scope variable names to be a little more readable.

`ng-repeat="student in students"` should be more readable `[singular] in [plural]`. This means that when reference each property you get `student.name` which makes much more sense at a glance.

I've also set your `indexOf` function to use angular's native `$index`. If this is not correct feel free to change back.

Your image's alt tag is not strictly a message to handle cases where the image load failed. Though your message would help for screen reader's it should really describe what the image is intended to be i.e. `Photograph of student's University`, if you want to display eror messages it would be advisable to use ng-if statements.

I would also recommend switching to `controllerAs` syntax and binding your data to the controller. You can read up on this [here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

model:

```
$scope.students = [{
  name: 'joe',
  university: 'someuni',
  image: 'image-name'
}];
```

template:

```
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li class="two" ng-repeat="student in students"> 
      <a class="link" href="#/details/{{$index}}">
        <!-- I would usually have the absolute url so taht any changes I need to make can be done in ctrl/srvc -->
        <img class="image" ng-src="{{student.image}}" alt="Photo is not availble" width="120"> 

        <p class="four">{{student.name | uppercase}}</br></p>
        <p class="five">{{student.univeristy | lowercase}} </p> 
      </a>
      <hr>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: oh crap I was using JPG instead of jpg :p worked fine thanks for helping